# Column space of the conjugate of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and let $\mathbf{A}^* \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ be its complex conjugate. Is the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ equal to the column space of $\mathbf{A}^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case $m = 2, n = 1$. We have $\begin{pmatrix}i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 1}$ are complex conjugates of each other, but they are linearly independent (with respect to both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$), so their column spaces are different.

I.e. $\text{Span} \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \right \} \neq \text{Span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \right\} $.

---

Edit: To address the comments by OP, firstly, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a $2$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, so the span of any particular vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$ cannot be all of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Next, more detail on why $\text{Span} \{v_1\} \neq \text{Span} \{v_2\}$, where $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Working over $\mathbb{C}$, it can be shown that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. This is enough to imply that $\text{Span} \{v_1\} \neq \text{Span} \{v_2\}$.

For if it were the case that $\text{Span} \{v_1\} = \text{Span} \{v_2\}$, since $v_1 \in \text{Span}\{v_1\}$, we would have $v_1 \in \text{Span} \{v_2\}$. So for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, we would have $v_1 = \lambda v_2 \iff v_1 - \lambda v_2 = 0$. But this contradicts the fact that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, so indeed $\text{Span} \{v_1\} \neq \text{Span} \{v_2\}$.

Comment: There is a contradiction, because both vectors have $\mathbb{C}^2$ as span, hence, their spans are equal!

Comment: Apparently, I fail to find the span of the complex vectors you mentioned in your example. Would you be kind to detail how you compute them and why they are different ? thanks.

Comment: @Likely I have edited my answer to address your comments. :)

Comment: Thank you, I see why I didn't get it before.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that an element in $\mathbb C^m$ is an ordered m-uple $(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_m)$ with $z_i \in \mathbb C$, clearly in general $A$ and $A^*$ don't share the same column space.

Indeed, let consider for example $(i,1)$ and $(-i,1)$ and let $z\in \mathbb C$ such that

$$z(i,1)=(iz,z)=(-i,1)$$

that is

- $iz=-i$
- $z=1$

which is impossible.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where the "therefore" come from!

Comment: @Likely If we are assuming that $z$ is a scalar on $ \mathbb C$ therefore the argument by Eh Wha is sufficient to show that column space are different.

Comment: Sorry again, but I also don't see how is it "clearly" not working in general! Particularly, not in the scalar case; assume $z$ scalar, then for me span($z$) = span($z^*$), since $\{az, \forall a \in \mathbb{C}\} = \{bz^*, \forall b \in \mathbb{C}\}$ (same set)

Comment: @LikelyI've added an example on that.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for the clear answer.